Differentiable voting loss
I have a problem which needs me to assign a class to each object in a scene (say 0 or 1) represented by an image. I am posing this as a segmentation problem (since there are many objects in a scene and I would like to process the whole scene at once). I know the object boundaries beforehand.
However, this means that the learned network produces a classification per pixel, rather than per object. I am using IoU and Dice losses which are common segmentation losses which seek to match the segmentation masks exactly.
I can then vote over all the pixels for an object to classify at the object level.
However, for me, the more important objective is per object class assignment accuracy. Since I use voting over pixels to determine the majority class, this is a non differentiable operation -- how can I turn this into a differentiable proxy that I can backprop through?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
